# Comparing values within an array to each other

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and HTML and am working on a small game.

I have four **'enemies'** whose position on the canvas is determined by the values in the arrays **'enemyX'** and **'enemyY'**.

Very simply, I want to detect if the enemies have **'collided'**, i.e have moved within `30px` of each other (the enemy image is 30px by 30px).

What I want to do is subtract the value of the ***i*** th value in the array with the other values in the *same array* and see if this value is less than **30**. The less than **30** part is an if statement, so how do I go about subtracting all the values from each other without many lines of code?

Here's what I have tried based on the answers below:

```
    var count = 0;
var innercount = 0;

while (count <= 3) {

    while (innercount<=3) {
        collisionDetect(count, innercount, enemyX[count], enemyY[count], enemyX[innercount], enemyY[innercount])
        innercount++
    }
    count++    
}

var i = 0;
while (i < enemyX.length) {

    if (collisionX[i] == 1) {
        directionX  = directionX*-1;
    }

    if (collisionY[i] == 1) {
        direction = directionY*-1;
    }
}


}



}

function   collisionDetect(count, innercount, x, y, xX, yY ) {


if ((Math.abs(x-xX)) <=30) {
    collisionX[count] = 1
    collisionX[innercount] = 1
}

if ((Math.abs(y - yY)) <=30) {
    collisionY[count] = 1
    collisionY[innercount] = 1
}

return collisionX, collisionY;
}
```

This code gives me a blank canvas.

Comment: Consider clarify your question. Add some pieces of code may help us to properly answer your question.

Comment: are `enemyX` and `enemyY` positioned in the center of the enemy object?

Comment: you can use jsfiddle to easily share your code.

Comment: Sorry. Question edited :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function:

```
function colliding(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  return Math.abs(x1-x2) <= 30 && Math.abs(y1-y2) <= 30;
}
```

then use the function to test the different combination of enemies: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), and (3,4).

So, for example, you would use: `colliding(enemyX[2], enemyY[2], enemyX[3], enemyY[3])` to check if enemy 2 and 3 are colliding. Do that with all the combinations above.

EDIT: to make it more readable, you could define an additional function:

```
function enemiesColliding(e1, e2){
  return colliding(enemyX[e1], enemyY[e1], enemyX[e2], enemyY[e2])
}
```

and then use it:

```
enemiesColliding(1,2) || enemiesColliding(1,3) || enemiesColliding(1,4) ||
enemiesColliding(2,3) || enemiesColliding(2,4) || enemiesColliding(3,4)
```

Comment: This doesn't take the corners into consideration, e.g. left top of A collides with right bottom of B.

Comment: @Jack: true; chanegd the check to `<=` instead of `<`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking of something similar to this, but I actually wanted something that used loops to minimize the amount of code i have to write. I think I can combine this with john B's loop within loop idea below.

Answer (score 1):

Detection of an intersection between two objects (assuming rectangular shape) and the position defines the center of the object.

```
function getRect(x, y, w, h)
{
    var left = x - Math.floor(w / 2),
    top = y - Math.floor(h / 2);

    return {
        left: left,
        top: top,
        right: left + w,
        bottom: top + h
    };
}

function intersects(A, B)
{
    return A.right >= B.left && 
       A.left <= B.right && 
       A.bottom >= B.top && 
       A.top <= B.bottom;
}

alert(intersects(getRect(12, 56, 30, 30), getRect(30, 40, 30, 30))); // true
```

The `getRect()` function can be modified to accommodate for a different anchor position, e.g. top left.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new. What do you mean by left:left, top:top, etc.?

Comment: Those are part of an object declaration in JavaScript, the property name is followed by a colon and the value.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to restate my understanding of you question, just so there is no confusion.
You have two arrays in paralleled , one for x cords, and one for y cords. Each ship has a element in both arrays.

So, for example, ship 12 could be found at xPos[12] and yPos[12], where xPos and yPos are the arrays from above.

It also stands to reason that this a communicative. If ship[a] collides with ship[b] then ship[b] has collided with ship[a]. And I think that hold for 3 + ships.

I would start by writing a distance function.

```
 dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
 {
     return Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
 }
```

Then I would write code run through the arrays.
Every element must be compared to every other element, one time.

```
 var counter = 0;
 var indexOfShipThatHaveCollided = [];
 while(counter < Xpos.length)
 {
      var innerCounter = counter;           
      while(innerCounter < Xpos.length)
      {
            t = dist(Xpos[counter],Ypos[counter],Xpos[innerCounter],Ypos[innerCounter])
            if(t < 30)
            {
                 indexOfShipThatHaveCollided.push(counter)
                 indexOfShipThatHaveCollided.push(innerCounter)

            }
      }

 }
```

The code above compares every ship to every other ship ONCE.
It will compare ship[1] to ship[8], but it will not compare ship[8] to ship[1].

I did not test ANY of this code, but I hope it moves you in the right direction. 
If you have anymore question just give me a comment.

Comment: It seems this code will also compare enemy[1] to enemy[1] once, giving a value of 0. Any workaround for that?

Comment: @user2392394: yes, use `var innerCounter = counter + 1`.

Comment: @Eduardo: Thanks, but then if counter = 2, then innercounter will only take the value 3. I also want innercounter to be 1, so that all the values are compared.

Comment: @JohnDoe: you don't need that. You will have already compared 1 and 2 when counter == 1 and innerCounter == 2.

Comment: You are correct. sorry about that bug, and thank you for correcting it. I will not update the code. I will leave the bug so others might learn from my error.

Answer (score 0):

According my understanding of your question below is my solution:

I think you need to find distance between two points. by using distance you can apply your logic.
To find distance following is the formula:

Given the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), 
the distance between these points is given by the formula:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think I wasn't able to clarify this in the question. My main problem is not finding the distance between the objects. I want to find a way to compare each object to every other object.